# Docker : invalid reference format on composer install

Tags: docker

I want to install the vendor folder of a project on docker, and I try to use this command:

```
winpty docker run --rm --interactive --tty \ --volume $(pwd):/app \ composer install
```

but after running it, I get the error message

> C:/Program Files/Docker/Docker/Resources/bin/docker.exe: invalid
>   reference format.

is there any solution to fix it?

Comment: Can you remove the '\ ' ? They don't look necessary

Answer (score 3):

In powershell you should use ${pwd} instead of $(pwd)